# Is SSD TRIM deleting your System Restore points in windows?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, restore, trim

I've had system restore enabled on Windows 7 with a SSD with TRIM enabled.

It would often have a message saying 'Creating restore point' but I never actually saw any restore points in the restore list.

Why is this?

Anyone confirm System Restore points are listed and are working correctly on an SSD with TRIM enabled?

(I know it's recommended to have it turned off, but I'm curious about how it functions with TRIM, if at all, or if it breaks TRIM operations somehow)

I've filled up free space with random files till it completely filled the SSD and I notice this wipes any restore points too. Does TRIM's affect on unallocated space somehow wipe System Restore points?

Comment: No; TRIM has nothing to do with system OS features outside of supporting TRIM itself.  System restore points would be effected by you filling the disk though

Comment: Why am I not seeing any restore points created? What possible conflicts could be causing it when using an SSD (with TRIM)?

Comment: System restore points requires available space otherwise the creation will fail if you fill up the drive the creation process fails

Comment: there's lots of available space, yet the restore points seem to not be created

Comment: Create a restoration point manually if it fails it will give you more information

Answer (score 0):

TRIM is a command that has to be issued by the OS. TRIM does not delete files, TRIM does not know about files.

TRIM, as I said, is a command that the OS can send to inform the drive (SSD or some SMR drives) that the logical sectors associated with the clusters that were allocated to for example files that are being deleted, can be discarded.

So IF a restore point is deleted, it is by doing of the operating system and the operating system can then decide to send TRIM commands to let the SSD know about the freed up space.